# Character value dividing number

Tags: sas

I expect the division operation should fail in both the cases since the operation is not between numeric values. First case works. Second case fails execution as expected. Can someone please explain the difference ? I am using SAS 9.04.

Case 1 (Working):

```
data work.products;
Product_Number = 11;
Item = '12';
Item_Reference = Item/Product_Number;
run;
```

Case 2 (Not working):

```
data work.products;
Product_Number = 11;
Item = '12';
Item_Reference = Product_Number/Item;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must be some sort of bug involving SAS 9.0 if case 1 works but case 2 doesn't. SAS should convert character values to numeric automatically if it detects that the string is a number. Your code works without a problem in SAS 9.4. Since automatic type conversion is not working for you, you can easily solve the problem by using the `input` function, or by multiplying the value by 1.

```
data work.products;
    Product_Number = 11;
    Item = '12';
    Item2 = input(Item, 8.);
    Item_Reference = Product_Number/Item2;
run;

data work.products;
    Product_Number = 11;
    Item = '12';
    Item2 = Item*1
    Item_Reference = Product_Number/Item2;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your both code is working

Case 1 as well as case 2 is working .

You are using the character variable for item which is basically a string. String contains both character as well as number. Your item only contains number in this case , SAS will treat value as numeric while performing the numerical operation for example

```
data work.products;
Product_Number = 11;
Item = '12a';
Item_Reference = Product_Number/Item;
run;
```

This program will give an error and place the missing value in item_reference . The log file would state the following :-

```
 NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by: (Line):(Column).
       59:33   
 NOTE: Invalid numeric data, Item='12a' , at line 59 column 33.
 Product_Number=11 Item=12a Item_Reference=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
 NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.
       Each place is given by: (Number of times) at (Line):(Column).
       1 at 59:32   
 NOTE: The data set WORK.PRODUCTS has 1 observations and 3 variables.
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.02 seconds
       cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

Hence while you are performing the numerical operation SAS tries to convert the character value into numeric format.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them should execute fine. The character values will be converted to numeric during calculation and you will get this message in the log:

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by: (Line):(Column).